# Logstash: timestamp pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, pattern-matching, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm looking for the pattern to use in my logstash configuration for these two timestamp:

```
2016-06-08 16:45:05 GMT+01:00
2016-06-19 00:01:00 CEST
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}` for both, that will work, but that won't capture the timezones properly.

Instead you can spell out the whole pattern like this for the first date:

```
%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} %{WORD}%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE}
```

And like this for the second date

```
%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND} %{WORD}
```

You might want to define a [custom pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns) out of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) , to make sure of your logstash configuration before adding it to your configuration filter.